# How to fill a C++ char[] with an JNI jobjectarray (Java String[])?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I think the question says it all. I work with the Android NDK. I cannot include std, no use of vectors please, just plain and simple c++.
Here's what I have so far:

```
// filePaths = jobjectarray = Java String[]
int elementCount = env->GetArrayLength(filePaths);

// this should end up being the char[] with the filePaths in it
char *cppFilePaths[elementCount];

for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
  jstring jFilePath = (jstring) (env->GetObjectArrayElement(filePaths, i));
  const char *cppFilePath = env->GetStringUTFChars(jFilePath, 0);

  // this does not work!
  cppFilePaths[i] = cppFilePath;

  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jFilePath, cppFilePath);
  env->DeleteLocalRef(jFilePath);
}
```

With this code I'll end up with `cppFilePaths` containing `elementCount` entries of the last String in `filePaths`.

I searched a lot and found out about `strcpy`or `memcpy`, but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

This works now. I have no idea, if it's okay to directly use the result of `GetStringUTFChars`, but until now no errors...

```
const char *cppFilePaths[elementCount] = {};

for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
  jstring jFilePath = (jstring) (env->GetObjectArrayElement(filePaths, i));
  cppFilePaths[i] = env->GetStringUTFChars(jFilePath, 0);
  env->DeleteLocalRef(jFilePath);
}
```

Comment: For every Get... You need a Release.... So you must allocate, copy and free if you want to keep the string values. Also the encoding you are copying from is modified UTF-8, which is fine if that's what you need in the native code.

Comment: could I ask you to rewrite the loop, so the "copy" part works? Using the code in my question, ´jFilePath` retained the same pointer address during the whole loop. This was the reason I ended up with the last string being in every element of `cppFilePaths`